# Redirecting specific URL to 404

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I set up a new website with WordPress. But Google still has a sitelink to a no longer existing page with a URL parameter: *domain.com/index.php?lang=EN* which points to a non-existent page and should therefore throw a 404 error. But somehow WordPress does show a page stating

> No blog posts have been added yet.

Due to not responding with a 404 error, the site does not disappear from Google Search Results!

How can I redirect incoming traffic from those two URLs:

- domain.com/index.php?lang=EN
- domain.com/index.php?lang=DE

to a 404 page? (I have set up a custom 404 page and added the *ErrorDocument 404* in my .htaccess-file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule on top of your .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?lang=(EN|DE)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```